# Is a junction box still considered accessible if behind stapled ceiling tiles?

Tags: electrical

I found a junction box underneath a drop ceiling. We are renovating and want to replace the drop ceiling with ceiling tile that can either be a drop ceiling or a flush mounted, stapled to joists. Of course we want the latter, stapled to joists. Does this mean the box is still considered accessible?

Comment: Would someone without prior knowledge of the box be able to find out that it is there and to locate it without breaking down the ceiling?

Comment: Will you be able to access the junction box cover without using any tools? Is there any reason you can't extend the box to extend through the new ceiling, and put a blank cover plate there?

Answer (score 3):

Your box would not be considered accessible if you staple your ceiling tile to the joist, unless you left a cover for it on the new ceiling tile. You might be able to flip the junction box and face it into the attic if that's an option. Otherwise you will need to move the junction to where you able to maintain it.